# Pandas: Can't access bold column values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to Pandas, and have a simple dataframe `data`:

```
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf  
data = yf.download('AAPL','2009-01-01','2019-01-01')
```

`data` contains the following:

[image]

I believe `list(data)` should show all column names, but it returns:

```
['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume']
```

How can I access the bolded column `Date` as an iterable? I'd be grateful for any help others can offer with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do `reset_index`:

```
data = data.reset_index()
```

And now:

```
print(list(data))
```

But also actually:

```
print(data.columns.tolist())
```

Is faster.

Output:

```
['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume']
```

It was like that because `'Date'` was the index column.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` seems `pandas.DataFrame` object

`DataFrame` consists of `index` and `columns`

In your `DataFrame` case

`['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Adj Close', 'Volume']` are columns

`['Date']` is index

`list(data)` only shows columns of `DataFrame`

So to get `date` as iterable you can try:

```
data.index
```

or as answered above you can move `index` to `columns` by:

```
data.reset_index()
```

either would work.